# How to implement a stable zoom in a mapping application

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm implementing a application with a click-and-drag and zoom functionality that is similar to Google Maps. I've managed to implement panning and zooming however, the zoom point is currently at the coordinates `0,0`. When you zoom in and out, the position of the grid at coordinates `0,0` stays fixed while all the other coordinates zoom closer/further from this point.

Instead, I would like to be able to implement a stable zoom where the zoom point is the location under the current mouse position. To get an idea of what I'm looking for, open Google Maps, position your mouse above a particular point and use the mouse wheel to scroll. Notice how the location under your mouse stays fixed.

How can I modify the `zoomGrid` function in this example to implement mouse wheel zooming that respects the position of the mouse?

```
function zoomGrid(mouseEvent) {
  var delta = mouseEvent.deltaY;
  if (mouseEvent.deltaMode == 1) { //Firefox scrolls by line instead of by pixel so multiply the delta by 20
    delta *= 20;
  }
  zoom += delta;
  zoom = Math.min(zoom, 3000);
  zoom = Math.max(zoom, -1000);
  scale = Math.pow(2,(zoom / 1000));

  var mousePos = {x: mouseEvent.offsetX, y: mouseEvent.offsetY};
  //gridPos = ???

  drawGrid();
  drawShapes();
}
```

Full demo: http://codepen.io/alexspurling/pen/jApazY

(PS I've already seen the [paper.js tutorial](http://matthiasberth.com/articles/stable-zoom-and-pan-in-paperjs/) but wasn't able to translate the logic there into workable code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution after some thought about exactly what it was that I was trying to do. The key insight was that the position of the mouse on the grid should be the same both before changing the scale and after.

With that in mind, all I had to do was record the position of the mouse before scaling:

```
var mousePos = {x: mouseEvent.offsetX, y: mouseEvent.offsetY};
var mouseGridPos = plus(multiply(mousePos, scale), gridPos);
```

Then adjust the scale as before:

```
var delta = mouseEvent.deltaY;
if (mouseEvent.deltaMode == 1) { //Firefox scrolls by line instead of by pixel so multiply the delta by 20
  delta *= 20;
}
zoom += delta;
zoom = Math.min(zoom, 3000);
zoom = Math.max(zoom, -1000);
scale = Math.pow(2,(zoom / 1000));
```

Then find the new grid position assuming the position at the mouse coordinates have not changed with the new scale:

```
//Calculate the grid position by using the previous scaled
//mouse position and the new scale
gridPos = minus(mouseGridPos, multiply(mousePos, scale));
```

I've created a new Code pen with working zooming here:

http://codepen.io/alexspurling/pen/xOJJdm

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that does what you want..

It is a little over kill for this answer but I am a little short on time to cut out the unneeded stuff.

The demo lets you zoom, pan and rotate. It first loads an image (reasonably sized so devices with low GPU RAM may not like it and run slow).

Once image of car has loaded.

- Left button drag to pan
- Wheel to zoom in and out
- Right button on down sets rotation origin, then drag away and around to rotate.
- Middle button will reset the view

To use just render at absolute coordinates. If you have a large dataset you can use the display Transform corners as the world coords view bounds when culling render calls..

The functions that are important are at the top.

- `display` is called once a frame and handles all the rendering
- `displayTransform` is the object that takes care of the pan, zoom, and rotate. It has some comments but not an explanation so feel free to ask question if you are having trouble
- `onResize` is called on debounced resize event
- `startup` is called once at startup and sets up displayTransform
- Boilerplate code at the bottom handles mouse and canvas and can be ignored.

`mouse` is a global object that hold the mouse state. 
`mouse.x`, `mouse.y` is the canvas coords
`mouse.buttonRaw` is the bit field Bit is on if button down. See next paragraph
`mouse.w` is the wheel -120, 0, or 120

`displayTransform.mouseWorldX` and `displayTransform.mouseWorldY` holds the location of the mouse on the image (as that will not match the canvas coord);
`displayTransform.corners` is an array of length 8 with coordinates of the canvas corners as [x1,y1,...,x4,y4] from topleft around in clockwise direction as projected onto the world (image) coordinates. You would use them to draw a grid and cull render calls outside the view.

I did not add any mouse button constants so when you see anything to do with mouse buttons 0 is left 1 is middle 2 is right as an ID. And when checking for mouse click the `mouse.buttonRaw` is a bit field with bit 1 left then 2 middle and 3 right. To mask only the button you are interested in  mouse.buttonRaw & 1`is left`&2`middle and`&4` right.

```js
var startup = function(){
    displayTransform.ctx = ctx;
    displayTransform.mouse = mouse;
    displayTransform.setMouseRotate(2); // set rotate funtion to button 3
    displayTransform.setMouseTranslate(0); 
    displayTransform.setWheelZoom();     
    img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Fiat_500_in_Emilia-Romagna.jpg"
}
var img;
var onResize = function(){
    ctx.font = "14px verdana";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    if(img.complete){
        displayTransform.fitView(0,0,img.width,img.height,"fit");
    }
}


var stillTime = 0;
const MOUSE_STILL_TIME = 1000;

function display(){
    displayTransform.update();// update the transform
    displayTransform.setDefault();// set home transform to clear the screem
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    // if the image loaded show it
    if(img.complete){
        if(displayTransform.quiet || (mouse.buttonRaw & 2)){
            stillTime += 1;
            if(stillTime > MOUSE_STILL_TIME || (mouse.buttonRaw & 2)){
                stillTime = 0;
                displayTransform.fitView(0,0,img.width,img.height,"fit")
            }
        }else{
            stillTime = 0;
        }
        displayTransform.setTransform();
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }else{
        // waiting for image to load
        displayTransform.setTransform();
        ctx.fillText("Loading image...",100,100);
    }
}


var displayTransform = (function(){
        
    const buttons = [1, 2, 4];
    
    // create a location description.
    // x and y is the position of the (where on the canvas the transformed point 0,0 will end up)
    // origin x,y is the location that zooms, rotations will be centered on.
    // scale is the scale (zoom) large numbers are zooming in small is zoom out. 1 is 1pixel = 1pixel
    // rotation is rotation. 0 id From left to right across the screen with positives values rotation
    // clockwise. Values are in radians
    var location = function (x, y, originX, originY, scale, rotation){
        return {
            x      : x,
            y      : y,
            ox     : originX,
            oy     : originY,
            scale  : scale,
            rotate : rotation,
        };
    }
    
    // returns an array to hold the transformation matrix
    // if a is undefined then returns the Identity (default) matrix
    var matrix = function (a, b, c, d, e, f){
        if(a === undefined){
            return [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
        }
        return [a, b, c, d, e, f];
    }
    
    // set the ctx transformation 
    var setTransform = function(){ 
        var m, i;
        m = this.matrix;
        i = 0;
        this.ctx.setTransform(m[i ++], m[i ++], m[i ++], m[i ++], m[i ++], m[i ++]);
    }
    
    // uses chase values to smooth out transformations and then sets the matrix and invMatrix
    // The inverMatrix is used to transform a point from world space to screen space.
    var smoothTransform = function(){
        var a, g, d, c, l, cross, m, im;
        // create short vars for code clarity
        a  = this.acceleration;
        g  = this.drag;
        l  = this.location;
        c  = this.locationChaser;
        d  = this.locationDelta;
        m  = this.matrix;
        im = this.invMatrix;
        
        // update the chasing value. Explination of code below
        // d += (l - c) * a;  // accelerate the delta
        // d *= g;            // apply the drag
        // c += d;            // add the new delta to the chasing value
        
        c.x      += (d.x      = (d.x      += (l.x      - c.x      ) * a ) * g);
        c.y      += (d.y      = (d.y      += (l.y      - c.y      ) * a ) * g);
        c.ox     += (d.ox     = (d.ox     += (l.ox     - c.ox     ) * a ) * g);
        c.oy     += (d.oy     = (d.oy     += (l.oy     - c.oy     ) * a ) * g);
        c.scale  += (d.scale  = (d.scale  += (l.scale  - c.scale  ) * a ) * g);
        c.rotate += (d.rotate = (d.rotate += (l.rotate - c.rotate ) * a ) * g);
        
        
        // use x and y movement to determin if the display has reached its position
        this.quiet = false;
        if(Math.abs(c.x - l.x) < 0.1 && Math.abs(c.y - l.y) < 0.1 && Math.abs(c.rotate - l.rotate) < 0.001 ){
            if(Math.abs(d.x) < 0.1 && Math.abs(d.y) < 0.1 && Math.abs(d.rotate) < 0.001){
                this.quiet = true;
            }
        }

        // calculate the matrix which is two vectors representing the X and Y axis
        // the Y axis is 90Deg counter clockwise from the X
        // To rotate a vector (v1) 90deg to (v2)
        // v2.x = -v1.y;  
        // v2.y =  v1.x;
        // m[0],m[1] is the X axies vector and m[2],m[3] is the Y axis vector
        m[3] =   m[0] = Math.cos(c.rotate) * c.scale;
        m[2] = -(m[1] = Math.sin(c.rotate) * c.scale);
        
        // transform the x,y position around the origin and add to the matrix
        m[4] = -(c.x * m[0] + c.y * m[2]) + c.ox;
        m[5] = -(c.x * m[1] + c.y * m[3]) + c.oy;
        
        // caculate the invers transformation
        
        // first get the cross product of x axis and y axis
        cross = m[0] * m[3] - m[1] * m[2];
        
        // now get the inverted axies
        im[0] =  m[3] / cross;
        im[1] = -m[1] / cross;
        im[2] = -m[2] / cross;
        im[3] =  m[0] / cross;
        im[4] = (m[1] * m[5] - m[3] * m[4]) / cross;
        im[5] = (m[2] * m[4] - m[0] * m[5]) / cross;        
        
        // all done for mow
    }

    // Activates mouse translate on button mouseButton 0 = main (left click) 1 = middle 2 = right
    var setUpMouseTranslate = function(mouseButton){
        this.mouseAction[mouseButton] = this.mouseTranslate.bind(this);
        this.mouseActionOff[mouseButton] = undefined;
    }
    // Does mouse drag translation 
    var mouseTranslate = function (mouse) {
        var mdx, mdy;
        
        // get the mouse delta
        var mdx = mouse.x - this.mouseLastX; // get the mouse movement
        var mdy = mouse.y - this.mouseLastY; // get the mouse movement
        
        // Transform the mouse delta to world space and move the 
        // world position
        this.location.x -= (mdx * this.invMatrix[0] + mdy * this.invMatrix[2]);
        this.location.y -= (mdx * this.invMatrix[1] + mdy * this.invMatrix[3]);   
    }
    
    // Set up mouse rotation on mouseButton 0 = main (left click) 1 = middle 2 = right
    // User clicks and drags. When a distance 14 pixels is reached the angle from the
    // start to that positoin is the referance. The user then drags around the
    // start point to rotate the world
    var setUpMouseRotate = function(mouseButton){
        // extra data needed to do the rotation
        this.rotationData = {
            rotateStart : false,      // the rotation has just started
            rotateOX    : 0,          // the screen start location of the rottae
            rotateOY    : 0,
            startAng    : undefined,  // the starting world rotatoin
            lastAng     : undefined,  // last angle input. Used to track cyclic rotation
            rotFrom     : undefined,  // the starting draged angle. 
        }
        this.mouseAction[mouseButton] = this.mouseRotate.bind(this);
        this.mouseActionOff[mouseButton] = (function(){
            this.rotationData.rotateStart = true;
        }).bind(this);
    }
    
    // Does the mouse drag rotation
    var mouseRotate = function (mouse) {
        var loc, mbx, mby, dist, rot, rd;
        loc = this.location;
        rd = this.rotationData;
        // is this the start of a rotation gesture
        // set the start location and the current rotation
        if(rd.rotateStart){
            rd.rotateStart = false;
            rd.rotateOX = mouse.x;
            rd.rotateOY = mouse.y;
            loc.ox = mouse.x;
            loc.oy = mouse.y;
            loc.x = this.mouseWorldX;
            loc.y = this.mouseWorldY;   
            rd.startAng = loc.rotate;
            rd.lastAng = undefined;
            rd.rotFrom = undefined;

            
        }
        // get mouse movement since start
        mdx = mouse.x - rd.rotateOX; 
        mdy = mouse.y - rd.rotateOY;
        dist = Math.hypot(mdy, mdx);
        if(dist > 14){   // tollerance (too close and the rotation goes all over thr plavce)
            rot = Math.atan2(mdy, mdx);  // get the angle from the start of the geusture to the mouse
            if(rd.lastAng === undefined){  // if the last ang is not avalible us the current angle
                rd.lastAng = rot;
                rd.rotFrom = rot;
            }
            // need to compensate for where atan2 goes from -Math.PI to Math.PI
            // adds 360 or subtracts 360 depending on which way around the user is draggin the mouse
            // can fail but I have been using this method for over 5 years
            // and have never had a problem
            if(rd.lastAng < -Math.PI / 2 && rot > Math.PI / 2 ){
                rd.startAng -= Math.PI * 2;
            }
            if(rd.lastAng > Math.PI / 2 && rot < -Math.PI / 2 ){
                rd.startAng += Math.PI * 2
            }
            loc.rotate = (rot-rd.rotFrom) + rd.startAng;
            rd.lastAng = rot; 
        }
        
    }
    

    // turns on wheel zoom
    var setWheelZoom = function(){
        this.mouseWheel = this.mouseWheelZoom;
    }
    
    // does wheel zoom
    var mouseWheelZoom = function (mouse) {
        var loc;
        loc = this.location;
        loc.ox = mouse.x;
        loc.oy = mouse.y;
        loc.x = this.mouseWorldX;
        loc.y = this.mouseWorldY;
        if(mouse.w > 0){ // zoom in
            loc.scale *= this.scaleSpeed;
            mouse.w -= 20;
            if(mouse.w < 0){
                mouse.w = 0;
            }
        }
        if(mouse.w < 0){ // zoom out
            loc.scale *= this.invScaleSpeed;
            mouse.w += 20;
            if(mouse.w > 0){
                mouse.w = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    



    // fits a location bound by x1,y1 and x2,y2 to fit within the 
    // canvas display
    // type "fit" will ensure that all the area is displayed. There my be gaps 
    //            above and below or left and right
    //      "fill" will ensure that the area fills the canva. there may be some 
    //             cliping to the sides of top. The image will be centered
    var setLocation = function (x1, y1, x2, y2, type){
        var w,h, vw, vh, loc;
        loc = this.location;
        w = this.ctx.canvas.width;
        h = this.ctx.canvas.height;
        loc.ox = w/2;
        loc.oy = h/2;
        vw = x2 - x1;
        vh = y2 - y1;
        if(type === "fit"){
            loc.scale = Math.min( w / vw, h / vh);
        }else{
            loc.scale = Math.max( w / vw, h / vh);
        }
        loc.x = (x1 + x2) / 2;// - (1 / loc.scale) * (w / 2);
        loc.y = (y1 + y2) / 2;// - (1 / loc.scale) * (h / 2);

        loc.rotate = Math.round(loc.rotate / (Math.PI * 2)) * Math.PI * 2;
    }
    // fits a location defined by x,y center and dx,dy the direction anddistance
    // to the right side

    var setOrientation = function (x, y, dx, dy){
        var w,h, vx, vy, loc, ang, size;
        loc = this.location;
        w = this.ctx.canvas.width;
        h = this.ctx.canvas.height;
        loc.ox = w/2;
        loc.oy = h/2;
        vx = dx - x;
        vy = dy - y;
        loc.rotate =- Math.atan2(vy, vx);
        size = Math.hypot(vx ,vy);
        loc.scale = w / (size*2);
        vx /= (size*2);
        vy /= (size*2);
        w = (1/loc.scale) * (w );
        h = (1/loc.scale) * (h );
        loc.x = x;// - w * vx - h * -vy;
        loc.y = y;// - w * vy - h * vx;
    }


    // update transformation should be called once per frame
    // Smooths and sets the transform on the current context (ctx).
    // if There is a mouse avalilble then get the mouse world position
    // and apply mouse gestures to update the world space.
    var updateWorld = function () {
        var msx, msy, im, m, loc, mouse, but, i, im0, im1, im2, im3, im4, im5, cor;
        but = buttons;
        m   = this.matrix;
        im  = this.invMatrix;
        loc = this.locationChaser;
        cor = this.corners;
        
        this.transform(); // update and set matrix
        
        im0 = im[0];
        im1 = im[1];
        im2 = im[2];
        im3 = im[3];
        im4 = m[4];
        im5 = m[5];
        
        
        if(this.mouse !== undefined){
            mouse = this.mouse;
            // caculate the mouse world coordinates
            msx = mouse.x - im4;
            msy = mouse.y - im5;
            this.mouseWorldX = (msx * im0 + msy * im2);
            this.mouseWorldY = (msx * im1 + msy * im3);                 
            i = 0;
            // do any mouse actions
            while( i < 3){
                if(this.mouseAction[i] !== undefined){
                    if((mouse.buttonRaw & but[i]) === but[i]){
                        this.mouseAction[i](mouse);
                    }else
                    if(this.mouseActionOff[i] !== undefined){
                        this.mouseActionOff[i](mouse);
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            if(this.mouseWheel !== undefined){
                if(mouse.w !== 0){
                    this.mouseWheel(mouse);
                }
            }
    
            // caculate the mouse world coordinates
            msx = mouse.x - im4;
            msy = mouse.y - im5;
            this.mouseWorldX = (msx * im0 + msy * im2);
            this.mouseWorldY = (msx * im1 + msy * im3);     

            
            
            
            // save old mouse position as the mouse events may occure more
            // offtent than the frame update. As we need the last position 
            // we used we stash the values here
            this.mouseLastX = mouse.x;
            this.mouseLastY = mouse.y;        
            
        }

        msx = -im4;
        msy = -im5;
        cor[0] = (msx * im0 + msy * im2);
        cor[1] = (msx * im1 + msy * im3);     
        msx =  this.ctx.canvas.width - im4;
        msy =  this.ctx.canvas.height - im5;
        cor[4] = (msx * im0 + msy * im2);
        cor[5] = (msx * im1 + msy * im3);     
        msx =   - im4;
        msy =  this.ctx.canvas.height - im5;
        cor[6] = (msx * im0 + msy * im2);
        cor[7] = (msx * im1 + msy * im3);         
        msx =  this.ctx.canvas.width - im4;
        msy =  - im5;
        cor[2] = (msx * im0 + msy * im2);
        cor[3] = (msx * im1 + msy * im3);   
        this.invScale = 1/loc.scale;
        this.pixelXx = im0;
        this.pixelXy = im1;     
    }

    // terms.
    // Real space, real, r (prefix) refers to the transformed canvas space.
    // c (prefix), chase is the value that chases a requiered value
    var displayTransform = {
        mode             : "smooth",
        location         : location(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
        locationChaser   : location(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
        locationDelta    : location(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
        corners          : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  // corners x,y start from top left to top right
        pixelXx          : 0,                         // the bot right to bot left
        pixelXy          : 0,
        transform        : smoothTransform,
        drag             : 0.1,  // drag for movements
        acceleration     : 0.7, // acceleration
        quiet            : false,   // this is true when most of the movement scaling and rotation have stopped
        matrix           : matrix(), // main matrix
        invMatrix        : matrix(), // invers matrix;
        mouseWorldX      : 0, // the mouse location in world space
        mouseWorldY      : 0, // the mouse location in world space
        mouseLastX       : 0, // the last mouse position in screen space
        mouseLastY       : 0,
        mouseAction      : [undefined, undefined, undefined],
        mouseActionOff   : [undefined, undefined, undefined],
        mouseWheel       : undefined,
        scaleSpeed       : 1.1,
        invScaleSpeed    : 1 / 1.1,
        mouseTranslate   : mouseTranslate,
        mouseRotate      : mouseRotate,
        mouseWheelZoom   : mouseWheelZoom,
        setMouseRotate   : setUpMouseRotate,
        setMouseTranslate: setUpMouseTranslate,
        setWheelZoom     : setWheelZoom,
        setTransform     : setTransform,
        setDefault       : function(){ this.ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); },
        update           : updateWorld,
        fitView          : setLocation,
        orientView       : setOrientation,
        ctx              : undefined,
        mouse            : undefined,
        
    } 
    return displayTransform;
})();






//==================================================================================================
// The following code is support code that provides me with a standard interface to various forums.
// It provides a mouse interface, a full screen canvas, and some global often used variable 
// like canvas, ctx, mouse, w, h (width and height), globalTime
// This code is not intended to be part of the answer unless specified and has been formated to reduce
// display size. It should not be used as an example of how to write a canvas interface.
// By Blindman67
const U = undefined;const RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 100;
var w,h,cw,ch,canvas,ctx,mouse,createCanvas,resizeCanvas,setGlobals,globalTime=0,resizeCount = 0; 
var L = typeof log === "function" ? log : function(d){ console.log(d); }
createCanvas = function () { var c,cs; cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style; cs.position = "absolute"; cs.top = cs.left = "0px"; cs.zIndex = 1000; document.body.appendChild(c); return c;}
resizeCanvas = function () {
    if (canvas === U) { canvas = createCanvas(); } canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.height = window.innerHeight; ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    if (typeof setGlobals === "function") { setGlobals(); } if (typeof onResize === "function"){ resizeCount += 1; setTimeout(debounceResize,RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME);}
}
function debounceResize(){ resizeCount -= 1; if(resizeCount <= 0){ onResize();}}
setGlobals = function(){ cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2; ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2; mouse.updateBounds(); }
mouse = (function(){
    function preventDefault(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
    var mouse = {
        x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false, buttonRaw : 0, over : false, bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], 
        active : false,bounds : null, crashRecover : null, mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
    };
    var m = mouse;
    function mouseMove(e) {
        var t = e.type;
        m.x = e.clientX - m.bounds.left; m.y = e.clientY - m.bounds.top;
        m.alt = e.altKey; m.shift = e.shiftKey; m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
        if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1]; }  
        else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2]; }
        else if (t === "mouseout") { m.buttonRaw = 0; m.over = false; }
        else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true; }
        else if (t === "mousewheel") { m.w = e.wheelDelta; }
        else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail; }
        if (m.callbacks) { m.callbacks.forEach(c => c(e)); }
        if((m.buttonRaw & 2) && m.crashRecover !== null){ if(typeof m.crashRecover === "function"){ setTimeout(m.crashRecover,0);}}        
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    m.updateBounds = function(){
        if(m.active){
            m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
        }
        
    }
    m.addCallback = function (callback) {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            if (m.callbacks === U) { m.callbacks = [callback]; }
            else { m.callbacks.push(callback); }
        } else { throw new TypeError("mouse.addCallback argument must be a function"); }
    }
    m.start = function (element, blockContextMenu) {
        if (m.element !== U) { m.removeMouse(); }        
        m.element = element === U ? document : element;
        m.blockContextMenu = blockContextMenu === U ? false : blockContextMenu;
        m.mouseEvents.forEach( n => { m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
        if (m.blockContextMenu === true) { m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false); }
        m.active = true;
        m.updateBounds();
    }
    m.remove = function () {
        if (m.element !== U) {
            m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => { m.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
            if (m.contextMenuBlocked === true) { m.element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);}
            m.element = m.callbacks = m.contextMenuBlocked = U;
            m.active = false;
        }
    }
    return mouse;
})();

// Clean up. Used where the IDE is on the same page.
var done = function(){
    window.removeEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas)
    mouse.remove();
    document.body.removeChild(canvas);    
    canvas = ctx = mouse = U;
    L("All done!")
}

resizeCanvas(); 
mouse.start(canvas,true); 
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas); 

function update(timer){ // Main update loop
    globalTime = timer;
    display();  // call demo code
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
startup();

/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the example. I've cleaned it up a bit to remove the bits I'm not so interested in (acceleration and rotating). You might like to update your answer if you like: http://codepen.io/alexspurling/pen/pbkLBk

However, I'm still completely lost as to how the transformation code works. Do you have an explanation or something else I could read to try to understand it?

Comment: @AlexSpurling Will improve it when time permits. The quick ver. Move mouse world pos `location.x y` back to 0,0 scale and then translate back to mouse canvas `location.ox oy` All done in smoothTransform  where I set m[4],m[5] If you dont need rotate change m[3] line to `m[3] = m[0] = c.scale` then line m[2] to `m[2] = m[1] = 0` then `m[4] = -c.x*c.scale+c.ox` and `m[5] = -c.y*c.scale + c.oy` may be easier to understand until I can fix the answer up. As you have the code I can remove the answer so someone else can give a better answer

Comment: @AlexSpurling forgot to add. ctx.setTransform(a,b,c,d,e,f) a,b is the vector representing the x axis, c,d is the vector representing the y axis, and e,f is the position where world coord 0,0 will be. `a` to `f` are all in screen pixel coords. x (a,b) and y (c,d) axis length is scale. When removing rotation x,y axis align to screen `[a,b] = [scale,0]` and `[c,d] = [0,scale]` this makes `b,c = 0`  remove parts multiplied by 0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using library for handling it?

http://leafletjs.com/ quite agnostic so you should be able to integrate it with your application.

Comment: Thanks that is a good suggestion but it probably won't be suitable for my application. I am building a simple canvas / paint application so I need direct access to the canvas. I'm looking for the general algorithm, not just a solution to my particular problem.