# How to bound image pan when zooming (HTML Canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to limit boundaries and I'm running into issues.  I'm upscaling an image from another canvas and then implementing zoom and pan.  My issue (code below) is with limiting/capping the offsetx/y so that you never see the whitespace; only parts of the image.

Pardon the mess! Any help is appreciated! :P

```js
var zoomIntensity = 0.2;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
var width = 200;
var height = 200;

var scale = 1;
var originx = 0;
var originy = 0;

var offset = {x:0, y:0};

//fill smaller canvas with random pixels
for(var x = 0; x < 100; x++)
for(var y = 0; y < 100; y++)
{
  var rando = function(){return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)};
  var val = rando();
  context2.fillStyle = "#" + val + val + val;
  context2.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
}

//draw the larger canvas
function draw()
{
  context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    
    // Clear screen to white.
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(originx - offset.x, originy - offset.y, width/scale, height/scale);
  context.drawImage(canvas2, 0,0, width, height);
}

// Draw loop at 60FPS.
setInterval(draw, 1000/60);

canvas.onmousewheel = function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // Get mouse offset.
    var mousex = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mousey = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    
    // Normalize wheel to +1 or -1.
    var wheel = event.wheelDelta/120;

    // Compute zoom factor.
    var zoom = Math.exp(wheel*zoomIntensity);
    
    // Translate so the visible origin is at the context's origin.
    context.translate(originx - offset.x, originy - offset.y); //offset is panning
    
    //make sure we don't zoom out further than normal scale
    var resultingScale = scale * zoom;
    if(resultingScale < 1)
     zoom = 1/scale;
  
    // Compute the new visible origin. Originally the mouse is at a
    // distance mouse/scale from the corner, we want the point under
    // the mouse to remain in the same place after the zoom, but this
    // is at mouse/new_scale away from the corner. Therefore we need to
    // shift the origin (coordinates of the corner) to account for this.
    originx -= mousex/(scale*zoom) - mousex/scale;
    originy -= mousey/(scale*zoom) - mousey/scale;
    
    // Scale it (centered around the origin due to the trasnslate above).
    context.scale(zoom, zoom);
    
    // Offset the visible origin to it's proper position.
    context.translate(-originx + offset.x, -originy + offset.y); //offset is panning

    // Update scale and others.
    scale *= zoom;
}

document.onkeydown = function (evt)
{
 var offsetx = 0;
  var offsety = 0;
  
 switch(evt.which)
 {
      case 37: //left
        offsetx = 1;
        break;
      case 38: //up
        offsety = 1;
        break;
      case 39: //right
        offsetx = -1
        break;
      case 40: //down
        offsety = -1;
        break;
  }
  
  offsetx /= scale;
  offsety /= scale;
  
  offset.x += offsetx;
  offset.y += offsety;
  
  context.translate(offsetx,offsety);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Using transformation matrix to constrain a view

To constrain the position you need to transform the corner coordinates of the image to screen coordinates. As getting the transform is still not standard across browsers the demo below holds a copy of the transform.

The object `view` holds the canvas view. When you use the function `view.setBounds(top,left,right,bottom);` the view will be locked to that area (the image you are viewing 0,0,100,100)

The scale and position (origin) will be constrained to keep the bounds outside or one the edge of the canvas context set by `view.setContext(context)`.

The function `scaleAt(pos,amount);` will scale at a specified pos (eg mouse position)

To set the transform use `view.apply()` this will update the view transform and set the context transform.

The are a few other functions that may prove handy see code.

Demo uses mouse click drag to pan and wheel to zoom.

Demo is a copy of the OP's example width modifications to answer question.

```js
// use requestAnimationFrame when doing any form of animation via javascript
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

var zoomIntensity = 0.2;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
var width = 200;
var height = 200;
context.font = "24px arial";
context.textAlign = "center";
context.lineJoin = "round"; // to prevent miter spurs on strokeText 
//fill smaller canvas with random pixels
for(var x = 0; x < 100; x++){
  for(var y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
    var rando = function(){return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)};
    var val = rando();
    if(x === 0 || y === 0 || x === 99 || y === 99){
        context2.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    }else{
        context2.fillStyle = "#" + val + val + val;
    
    }
    context2.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
  }
}

// mouse holds mouse position button state, and if mouse over canvas with overid
var mouse = {
    pos : {x : 0, y : 0},
    worldPos : {x : 0, y : 0},
    posLast : {x : 0, y : 0},
    button : false,
    overId : "",  // id of element mouse is over
    dragging : false,
    whichWheel : -1, // first wheel event will get the wheel
    wheel : 0,
}

// View handles zoom and pan (can also handle rotate but have taken that out as rotate can not be contrained without losing some of the image or seeing some of the background.
const view = (()=>{
    const matrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0]; // current view transform
    const invMatrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0]; // current inverse view transform
    var m = matrix;  // alias
    var im = invMatrix; // alias
    var scale = 1;   // current scale
    const bounds = {
        topLeft : 0,
        left : 0,
        right : 200,
        bottom : 200,
    }
    var useConstraint = true; // if true then limit pan and zoom to 
                              // keep bounds within the current context
    
    var maxScale = 1;
    const workPoint1 = {x :0, y : 0};
    const workPoint2 = {x :0, y : 0};
    const wp1 = workPoint1; // alias
    const wp2 = workPoint2; // alias
    var ctx;
    const pos = {      // current position of origin
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
    }
    var dirty = true;
    const API = {
        canvasDefault () { ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0) },
        apply(){
            if(dirty){ this.update() }
            ctx.setTransform(m[0],m[1],m[2],m[3],m[4],m[5]);
        },
        getScale () { return scale },
        getMaxScale () { return maxScale },
        matrix,  // expose the matrix
        invMatrix, // expose the inverse matrix
        update(){ // call to update transforms
            dirty = false;
            m[3] = m[0] = scale;
            m[1] = m[2] = 0;
            m[4] = pos.x;
            m[5] = pos.y;
            if(useConstraint){
                this.constrain();
            }
            this.invScale = 1 / scale;
            // calculate the inverse transformation
            var cross = m[0] * m[3] - m[1] * m[2];
            im[0] =  m[3] / cross;
            im[1] = -m[1] / cross;
            im[2] = -m[2] / cross;
            im[3] =  m[0] / cross;
        },
        constrain(){
            maxScale = Math.min(
                ctx.canvas.width / (bounds.right - bounds.left) ,
                ctx.canvas.height / (bounds.bottom - bounds.top)
            );
            if (scale < maxScale) {  m[0] = m[3] = scale = maxScale }
            wp1.x = bounds.left;
            wp1.y = bounds.top;
            this.toScreen(wp1,wp2);
            if (wp2.x > 0) { m[4] = pos.x -= wp2.x }
            if (wp2.y > 0) { m[5] = pos.y -= wp2.y }
            wp1.x = bounds.right;
            wp1.y = bounds.bottom;
            this.toScreen(wp1,wp2);
            if (wp2.x < ctx.canvas.width) { m[4] = (pos.x -= wp2.x -  ctx.canvas.width) }
            if (wp2.y < ctx.canvas.height) { m[5] = (pos.y -= wp2.y -  ctx.canvas.height) }
        
        },
        toWorld(from,point = {}){  // convert screen to world coords
            var xx, yy;
            if(dirty){ this.update() }
            xx = from.x - m[4];     
            yy = from.y - m[5];     
            point.x = xx * im[0] + yy * im[2]; 
            point.y = xx * im[1] + yy * im[3];
            return point;
        },        
        toScreen(from,point = {}){  // convert world coords to screen coords
            if(dirty){ this.update() }
            point.x =  from.x * m[0] + from.y * m[2] + m[4]; 
            point.y = from.x * m[1] + from.y * m[3] + m[5];
            return point;
        },        
        scaleAt(at, amount){ // at in screen coords
            if(dirty){ this.update() }
            scale *= amount;
            pos.x = at.x - (at.x - pos.x) * amount;
            pos.y = at.y - (at.y - pos.y) * amount;            
            dirty = true;
        },
        move(x,y){  // move is in screen coords
            pos.x += x;
            pos.y += y;
            dirty = true;
        },
        setContext(context){
            ctx = context;
            dirty = true;
        },
        setBounds(top,left,right,bottom){
            bounds.top = top;
            bounds.left = left;
            bounds.right = right;
            bounds.bottom = bottom;
            useConstraint = true;
            dirty = true;
        }
    };
    return API;
})();
view.setBounds(0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);
view.setContext(context); 



//draw the larger canvas
function draw(){
    view.canvasDefault(); // se default transform to clear screen
  context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    view.apply();  // set the current view
  context.drawImage(canvas2, 0,0);
    view.canvasDefault();
    if(view.getScale() === view.getMaxScale()){
       context.fillStyle = "black";
       context.strokeStyle = "white";
       context.lineWidth = 2.5;
       context.strokeText("Max scale.",context.canvas.width / 2,24);
       context.fillText("Max scale.",context.canvas.width / 2,24);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    if(mouse.overId === "canvas"){
        canvas.style.cursor = mouse.button ? "none" : "move";
    }else{
        canvas.style.cursor = "default";
    }
}
// add events to document so that mouse is captured when down on canvas
// This allows the mouseup event to be heard no matter where the mouse has
// moved to.
"mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mousewheel,wheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
    .forEach(eventName=>document.addEventListener(eventName,mouseEvent));

function mouseEvent (event){
    mouse.overId = event.target.id;
    if(event.target.id === "canvas" || mouse.dragging){ // only interested in canvas mouse events including drag event started on the canvas.

        mouse.posLast.x = mouse.pos.x;
        mouse.posLast.y = mouse.pos.y;    
        mouse.pos.x = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        mouse.pos.y = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;    
        view.toWorld(mouse.pos, mouse.worldPos); // gets the world coords (where on canvas 2 the mouse is)
        if (event.type === "mousemove"){
            if(mouse.button){
                view.move(
                   mouse.pos.x - mouse.posLast.x,
                   mouse.pos.y - mouse.posLast.y
                )
            }
        } else if (event.type === "mousedown") { mouse.button = true; mouse.dragging = true }        
        else if (event.type === "mouseup") { mouse.button = false; mouse.dragging = false }
        else if(event.type === "mousewheel" && (mouse.whichWheel === 1 || mouse.whichWheel === -1)){
            mouse.whichWheel = 1;
            mouse.wheel = event.wheelDelta;
        }else if(event.type === "wheel" && (mouse.whichWheel === 2 || mouse.whichWheel === -1)){
            mouse.whichWheel = 2;
            mouse.wheel = -event.deltaY;
        }else if(event.type === "DOMMouseScroll" && (mouse.whichWheel === 3 || mouse.whichWheel === -1)){
            mouse.whichWheel = 3;
            mouse.wheel = -event.detail;
        }
        if(mouse.wheel !== 0){
            event.preventDefault();
            view.scaleAt(mouse.pos, Math.exp((mouse.wheel / 120) *zoomIntensity));
            mouse.wheel = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
div { user-select: none;}   /* mouse prevent drag selecting content */
canvas { border:2px solid black;}
```

```html
<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<p>Mouse wheel to zoom. Mouse click drag to pan.</p>
<p>Zoomed image constrained to canvas</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `mousewheel` is deprecated and not widely supported. `wheel` is what you want.

Comment: Can't say I understand what's going on 100%, but it works.  I'll have to try and break it apart.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice example. Helped me a lot. Just one question. Why don't you use drag events and instead you are working with mouse move, down and up?

Comment: @HristoEnev I dont use drag events to keep the code as simple as possible. This is especially true for the canvas that does not provide a UI (such as buttons, sliders, etc) where all the mouse/pointer events will also be interacting with custom input elements/objects that have no DOM analogy . Though there is no reason you can not use which ever events you see fit, eg scroll events for zoom, etc

Comment: in mouseEvent function better to use OffsetX

  `      mouse.pos.x = event.offsetX;
        mouse.pos.y = event.offsetY;   `

Comment: @user889030 offset at time of answer (and still) is marked as "experimental technology" by MDN and is thus subject to change. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX