# Limit drag on image after zoom in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, drag

I have been playing with canvas the last few days, and while I have achieved most of what I want to do I am struggling with one issue. I can load, zoom & move an image without problems.

However, after zooming an image in a canvas element, I want to be able to drag that image, but limit the drag so that the right edge of the zoomed image can not be moved beyond the right edge of the canvas, the left edge of the zoomed image, never beyond the left edge of the canvas etc

The effect I am trying to achieve is exactly that which is produced in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjAWEqrdnL6skKQYsFM2?p=preview).

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {

    var obj;
    obj = e.target;
    obj.setCoords();

    var boundingRect = obj.getBoundingRect();
    var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
    var viewportMatrix = canvas.viewportTransform;

    //there is a bug in fabric that causes bounding rects to not be 
    transformed by viewport matrix
    //this code should compensate for the bug for now

    boundingRect.top = (boundingRect.top - viewportMatrix[5]) / zoom;
    boundingRect.left = (boundingRect.left - viewportMatrix[4]) / zoom;
    boundingRect.width /= zoom;
    boundingRect.height /= zoom;


    // if object is too big ignore

    if (obj.currentHeight * zoom > obj.canvas.height * zoom || obj.currentWidth * zoom > obj.canvas.width * zoom) {
        return;
    }

    var canvasHeight = obj.canvas.height / zoom,
    canvasWidth = obj.canvas.width / zoom,
    rTop = boundingRect.top + boundingRect.height,
    rLeft = boundingRect.left + boundingRect.width;

    // top-left  corner
    if (rTop < canvasHeight || rLeft < canvasWidth) {
        obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, canvasHeight - boundingRect.height);
        obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, canvasWidth - boundingRect.width);
    }


    // bot-right corner
    if (boundingRect.top + boundingRect.height > obj.canvas.height || boundingRect.left + boundingRect.width > obj.canvas.width) {

        obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height - boundingRect.height + obj.top - boundingRect.top);
        obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width - boundingRect.width + obj.left - boundingRect.left);
    }
    //canvas.sendToBack(canvas.getObjects()[0])
}
```

However I am not using fabric js. [Here is a fiddle with the code I am using](https://jsfiddle.net/Lathamios/m0dfbzL8/40/)

Any help as to how I can achieve this would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/44015705/3877726

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks a lot!